# Can I tell if a user is the same as a previously deleted user?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

Occasionally a problem user self deletes, then comes back, possibly with the account association bonus; *or at least seems to*.  We can speculate about similar profiles and gravatars, but I don't see an obvious way to confirm if they are indeed the same user.  This creates headaches for the moderators because we treat repeat offenders differently than new users learning the site.

Is there a way I can *confirm* my suspicions that a user is the same one who previously deleted an account?

Comment: By asking the team.

Comment: Well, exact same identicon means the same email hash so pretty sure same person.

Comment: @Manishearth Email to team@?

Comment: @C.Ross Or ping one of them in the Teacher's Lounge, yes

Answer (score 8):

You can, if you happen to know the user's old profile. Visiting it as a moderator will bring up the fact that the account was previously deleted, and why.

If you *strongly* suspect that this is the case and don't happen to remember where their profile used to live, just ping one of the people on the community team and ask us to check. We can *sometimes* dig it up and find out for sure.

This *might* be something we can make available to mods so you can cross reference this yourself, but it means bringing a few sort of kludgey tools together into one, and it has limited use. You should only be looking into this if the user has returned and is demonstrating the same problematic behavior all over again - but presumably, if you're trying to nail this down, they *have*.

Certain changes in the pipe will make it *extremely* difficult for users that have been asked to leave the site and removed to return, but we do need to do more in the case of users self-deleting after being sanctioned for something, then just returning and repeating the same behavior.

We'll look at it and see what we can do.